# How to execute .bat from classpath in java?

Tags: java, batch-file

How to execute `.bat` from `classpath`? I can only execute `.bat` the specific directory like `D:\temp\kill-chrome.bat`.

ClassPath Directory

```
+ src
    + -> .java files ....
+ resource
    + kill-chrome.bat
```

My Program does not work.

```
String path = "cmd /c start /resource/kill-chrome.bat";
Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process pr = rn.exec(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got simplest way which is using `file.getAbsolutePath()` method. I am not sure which is suitable way or not.

```
String realPath = new File("resource/kill-chrome.bat").getAbsolutePath();
String path = "cmd /c start " + realPath;
Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process pr = rn.exec(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In `runtime.exec(commend)`, cannot directly to access the `classpath`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to get the path of a file in your classpath would be something like this:

```
URI uri = YourClass.class.getResource("resource/kill-chrome.bat").toURI();
String path = new File(uri).getAbsolutePath();
```

This aproach would go from your working directory (and this could differ):

```
new File("resource/kill-chrome.bat").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. It is another topic, file loading strategy base on the application nature like web application.